# Unable to iterate values returned by query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to retrieve values from the native query but If I have the returned type as `Object[]`. I am getting a typecast error. If I have it as `BigInteger[]` I get only one value.

```
    @Query(value = "select  coalesce(sum(individual),0) as individual, 
    coalesce(sum(groups),0) as groups, coalesce(sum(habitation),0) as habitation, coalesce(sum(works),0) as works,"+
        "  coalesce(sum(others),0) as others,"+
        "  coalesce(sum(online),0) as online, coalesce(sum(standalone),0) as standalone, coalesce(sum(excel),0) as excel, coalesce(sum(manual),0) as manual,"+
        "  coalesce(sum(working),0) as working, coalesce(sum(not_working),0) as not_working, coalesce(sum(under_development),0) as under_development,"+
        "  coalesce(sum(nic),0) as nic, coalesce(sum(cgg),0) as cgg, coalesce(sum(portal_others),0) as portal_others"+
        " from( select dept_id,scheme_id, sub_scheme_id,"+
        "      case when beneficiary_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end as individual,"+
        "      case when beneficiary_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end as groups,"+
        "      case when beneficiary_type = 4 then 1 else 0 end as habitation,"+
        "      case when beneficiary_type = 5 then 1 else 0 end as works,"+
        "      case when beneficiary_type = 6 then 1 else 0 end as others,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end as online,"+
        "      case when system_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end as standalone,"+
        "      case when system_type = 3 then 1 else 0 end as excel,"+
        "      case when system_type = 4 then 1 else 0 end as manual,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 and system_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end as working,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 and system_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end as not_working,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 and system_status = 3  then 1 else 0 end as under_development,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 and software_developed_by = '1' then 1 else 0 end as cgg,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 and software_developed_by = '2' then 1 else 0 end as nic,"+
        "      case when system_type = 1 and (software_developed_by = '0' or  software_developed_by = '99') then 1 else 0 end as portal_others"+
        "    from scheme_details " +
        "    where is_deleted is false"+
        "  )t", nativeQuery = true)
public BigInteger[] queryWithCaseValues();
```

Comment: Can you give us exception details regarding type cast? (stacktrace)

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger. This happens when i have the method as public Object[] queryWithCaseValues();

Comment: change your method to: public Object[] queryWithCaseValues();

Comment: Provide a complete example with error.

Comment: Your query returns multiple columns, so they cannot map to 1 BigInteger obviously

Answer (score 0):

So There was a lot of conversion that i had to do in order to retrieve the fields

```
 Object[] schemeDetailValues = (Object[])schemeDetailCount[0];
    BigInteger[] retrieveValues = retrieveschemeDetailValues(schemeDetailValues);
        adminDashboardCommand.setIndividualBeneficiaryCount(retrieveValues[0].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setGroupBeneficiaryCount(retrieveValues[1].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setHabitationBeneficiaryCount(retrieveValues[2].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setWorksBeneficiaryCount(retrieveValues[3].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setOthersBeneficiaryCount(retrieveValues[4].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setTotalBeneficiaryCount(retrieveValues[5].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setOnlineSystemsAvailableCount(retrieveValues[6].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setStandaloneSystemsAvailableCount(retrieveValues[7].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setExcelUploadSystemAvailableCount(retrieveValues[8].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setManualSystemsAvailableCount(retrieveValues[9].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setTotalSystemsAvailableCount(retrieveValues[10].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setWorkingSystemsCount(retrieveValues[11].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setNonWorkingSystemsCount(retrieveValues[12].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setUnderDevelopmentSystemsCount(retrieveValues[13].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setNicWebsiteCount(retrieveValues[14].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setCggWebsiteCount(retrieveValues[15].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setOthersWebsiteCount(retrieveValues[16].intValue());
        adminDashboardCommand.setTotalWebsiteCount(retrieveValues[17].intValue());
```

So I am confused as to how Spring Data simplifies development. It seems that only for simple mappings that JPA is useful. When it comes down to native queries its a awful lot of data conversion. Can someone enlighten me on why so many enterprises use it when the complexity increases it as good as using JDBC.

Thanks,
Manoj